# jQuery append to jQuery variable instead of DOM element

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to append to jQuery variable?

someting like this `$($tnail).appendTo($collection);`

I need to optimize costly DOM modifications and want to do it all at once.

something like this:

```
    var $collection;

 $.each(items, function (i, item) {

        var $tnail = $("<div></div>");

        $($tnail).appendTo($collection);

    });

    $($collection).appendTo("#Container");
```

Comment: In your code `$collection` should be a jQuery object.

Comment: If you really want to optimize, you'll do [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/hPjJS/4/) !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! You just need to make sure `$collection` is a jQuery object:

```
var $collection = $('<x/>');

$.each(items, function (i, item) {

    var $tnail = $("<div></div>");

    $tnail.appendTo($collection);

});

$($collection.html()).appendTo("#Container");
```

You've also got 2 bits where you wrap a jQuery object in a new jQuery call: `$tnail` is already a jQuery wrapped div, so it already has the `appendTo` method. Even more performance benefits!

**EDIT:** As Kevin points out, you can't append to an empty jQuery object. Internally, jQuery uses empty document fragments, but it doesn't expose this through it's API. So I've change my solution to create a dummy element, and then only append its *contents* to `#Container`.

Comment: I'm not sure what the result of this code will be, `$collection` doesn't contain any elements for `$tnail` to be appended to. I'd expect it to do nothing

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually want to append the elements to $collection, you want to add them to it.

```
var $collection = $(); // must be a jquery object
$.each(items, function (i, item) {

    var $tnail = $("<div></div>");

    // add to collection
    $collection.add($tnail);

});
```